# php include navbar not working

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap

I've been doing research on how to implement and use php include (or require), unfortunately I am running into some issues.

I am making a website for my class and I am trying to call my bootstrap navbar externally as a .php file, unfortunately it doesn't work regardless if I try using include or require. I've Googled to see what potential issues I am running into, but I haven't found anything yet. I am hoping someone experienced with php might spot whatever mistake I am encountering a bit easier.

Thank You

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <!-- The above 3 meta tags *must* come first in the head; any other head co$
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="images/favicon.ico">

    <title>JR Audi | Audi New & Used Car Dealership</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="styles$

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="jraudi.css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>
<!-- NAVBAR
================================================== -->
  <body>

<?php require 'navbar.php';?>

    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min$
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <!-- IE10 viewport hack for Surface/desktop Windows 8 bug -->
    <script src="http://getbootstrap.com/assets/js/ie10-viewport-bug-workaround$
  </body>
</html>
```

PHP:

```
 <?php

    <!-- Static navbar -->
        <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbar" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="navbar">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
        </div>
        <div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/lab4/jraudi">Home</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">New <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">New Audi Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Featured New Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Showroom</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Pre Owned <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Pre Owned Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Featured Pre Owned Inventory</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Showroom</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Finance <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Finance Application</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Getting Started</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Finance A Vehicle</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/lab3/lab3.html">Ownership Survey</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Service & Parts <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">Schedule Service</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Service Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Maintenance Schedules</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parts Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Parts Special</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Tire Center</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Audi Roadside Assistance</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Specials <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="#">New Vehicle Incentives</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Pre-owned Specials</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/certified.html">CPO Specials</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/audi-supplier-program.html">Audi Supplier Program</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/finance.html">Finance Specials</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/service.html">Service Specials</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/parts.html">Parts Specials</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">About <span class="caret"></span></a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/about.html">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/contact.html">Contact and Hours</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/directions.html">Directions</a></li>
                <li><a href="http://ps11.pstcc.edu/~c2230a11/website/employment.html">Employment</a></li>
            </ul>
            </li>

            <button onclick="location.href = 'login';" id="Button"
            class="btn btn-default navbar-btn pull-right" >LogIn / SignUp</button>


            <form class="navbar-form navbar-right" role="search">
            <div class="form-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Year, Make, Model, etc.">
            </div>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Search</button>
            </form>

              </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
        </div><!--/.container-fluid -->
        </nav>
        ?>
```

Comment: Is your nav bar in the same directory as the top html page you provided?

Comment: Are you getting an error? Are the files in the same directory? You navbar file is straight html in PHP tags. That won't output anything.

Comment: Im surprised you havent seen errors. Your nav info is surrounded by `<?php ?>` but all that is is HTML. remove those tags.

Comment: Yeah all the files are in the same directory, copied the ?php? stuff from W3 schools, but Ill delete it and see what happens

Comment: can you provide the link of W3C Schools so that we can see what you mean?

Comment: Of course: [W3 School Example I Followed](http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_includes.asp) . So I am using the same nav bar across roughly 10 webpages, my teacher said I should place the nav bar into a .php file and then call that php file in my .html file, so that's what I've been attemping. I'm very new to this, I am learning it right now, so I do apologize for any foolish errors I make.

Comment: Update: Apparently I had some redundancy in addition to calling a .php into a .html format. I changed everything over to .php so things could parse easier, changed my code slightly and everything worked

Answer (score 1):

Remove `<?php` `?>` tags from include file

Answer (score 0):

Your included file contains `<?php` staring and `?>` ending tag, but content looks like HTML. Just remove this tags.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this issue too. Another thing to look out for is making sure the file has the correct permissions. The right html may print out in the terminal but not in your browser.